# ArcGIS freezes when opening most toolboxes

Tags: arcmap, geoprocessing, kml, arctoolbox, layer-to-kml

I'm using ArcGIS 10.6.1 on Windows 10.

I work from home using a VPN to connect to my university's network. It's been nearly impossible to open any dialog boxes. For instance, I frequently use the Layer to KML tool, but the program hangs when I open it. The dialog box pops up, but then it never populates with any fields and I'm left with a white box. I have to shut down all of ArcMap and restart. No error messages or anything. I've left it running for a full half hour and it never resumes.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Even when I copy all the relevant files locally and do the same thing, it still freezes.

Comment: Does this only occur when connected through VPN?  Do you have VPN resources in the attached folders list?

Comment: @Vince I copied the files locally and tried working when I wasn't connected to the VPN and the same thing still happened. I removed the VPN resources in the Folder Connections list, and it still occurs.

Comment: I also tried the suggestions posted [in this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16655/arcgis-incredibly-slow-when-opening-any-toolbox-tool?rq=1) (changing the OpLocksDisabled registry setting), but it is still freezing.

Comment: Time to call in Tech Support.